# Setting width of heading image in docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

im trying to define 2 images as header and a image as footer, but cant seem to resize it correctly.

```
        docpath="/Users/ricardosimoes/Desktop/DESKTOP/Jira/my_word_file.docx"
        mydoc = docx.Document()
        section_h = mydoc.sections[0]
        header = section_h.header


        styles = mydoc.styles
        style = styles.add_style('Tahoma',WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
        style.font.name = 'Tahoma'
        style.font.size = Pt(11)

        shd = OxmlElement('w:background')
        # Add attributes to the xml element
        shd.set(qn('w:color'), '#0000FF')
        shd.set(qn('w:themeColor'), 'text1')
        shd.set(qn('w:themeTint'), 'F2')
        # Add background element at the start of Document.xml using below
        mydoc.element.insert(0, shd)
        # Add displayBackgroundShape element to setting.xml
        shd1 = OxmlElement('w:displayBackgroundShape')
        mydoc.settings.element.insert(0, shd1)

        paragraph_h = header.paragraphs[0]
        runheader = paragraph_h.add_run()
        runheader.add_picture("client_report/report_img/titulo.png", width=docx.shared.Inches(5), height=docx.shared.Inches(1))

        paragraph_h = header.paragraphs[0]
        runheader = paragraph_h.add_run()
        runheader.add_picture("client_report/report_img/titulo_logo.png", width=docx.shared.Inches(5), height=docx.shared.Inches(1))


        mydoc.add_picture("client_report/report_img/bottom.png", width=docx.shared.Inches(5),
                          height=docx.shared.Inches(1))
        mydoc.save(docpath)
```

I need to specify that the titulo.png and bottom.png fit width of the page and the titulo_logo.png set in front of the titulo.png on the bottom corner left of the image.

Can this be done?

Comment: An inline image cannot be "stacked" on top of anything else, so you won't be able to put one of these images "in front" of another.

Comment: @scanny ok, thanks, i guess i have to make a header banner for each logo. any ideias ao to fit them to the page width?

Comment: If you want them side by side, a common approach is to use a table with one row and two cells, then place your content into the cells.